# change color of menu item when on sub-menu page

Tags: wordpress

I am building a site in Wordpress using Starkers theme.  I have used html to code the main and sub navigations and styled in css.  What I am needing to do is make each of the main nav links to change color when on their page and for the parent of the sub menu to be a different color when on their pages.  I have tried using current-menu-item and current-parent-item, but neither work.  Any ideas???  http://page12.com.au/sample.html

My code:

```
    nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: 'HelveticaNeuel';
    color: rgb(146, 148, 151);
    }

nav ul li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 40px;
    font-family: 'HelveticaNeuel';
    color: rgb(146, 148, 151);
}

/*position home, folio, contact */

nav ul li.right a {
    margin-left: 600px;
}

nav ul li.left1 a {
    margin-left: 20px;
}

nav ul li.center {
    margin-left: 40px;
}

nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'HelveticaNeuel';
    color: rgb(146, 148, 151);
}

nav a:hover {
    color: rgb(164, 130, 46); 
}

nav ul li ul {
    display: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 800px;
}

nav ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    /*left: 0;*/
}

nav ul li ul li {
    padding: 10px;
}

/* sub navigation */

#sub-nav {
    width: 960px;
    height: 35px;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 5px 0 0 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 30px;
}

    #sub-nav li {
        display: inline;
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        position: relative;
        float: left;
    }

    #sub-nav a {
        text-decoration: none;
        font-family: 'HelveticaNeuel';
        color: rgb(146, 148, 151);
    }

    #sub-nav a:active {
        color: rgb(164, 130, 46); 
    }

    /*sub menu selected page font colour change */
    #sub-nav li.selected a {
        color: rgb(164, 130, 46);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You will get below class on active and parent page on **li** tag.

- current-menu-item
- current-menu-ancestor
- current-menu-parent
- current_page_parent
- current_page_ancestor

According to ablove class you can give css for that.

```
#nav {
    background:#333;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
}
#nav ul {
    float:left;
    margin:0;
}
#nav ul > li {
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;  
}
#nav li > a {
    color:#fff;
    font-size:14px;
    padding:10px 20px;
    display:block;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
#nav li:hover > a ,
#nav li.current-menu-item > a,
#nav li.current-menu-ancestor > a,
#nav li.current_page_item > a,
#nav li.current_page_ancestor > a, 
#nav li.current_page_parent > a {
    background:#212121;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#nav ul ul {
    position:absolute;
    top:36px;
    left:0;
    background:#fff;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    border-top:none;
    padding:7px 0;
    display:none;
}
#nav ul ul ul {
    left:100%;
    top:0;
}
#nav li li {
    width:160px;
}
#nav li li > a {
    font-size:12px;
    color:#7e7e7e;
    padding:5px 20px;
}
#nav li li:hover > a ,
#nav li li.current-menu-item > a,
#nav li li.current-menu-ancestor > a,
#nav li li.current_page_item > a,
#nav li li.current_page_ancestor > a,
#nav li li.current_page_parent > a {
    background:#fff;
    color:#232323;
}
#nav li:hover ul {
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work.  I'm not sure why the current-menu etc are not working.

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out myself.  I needed to use the body.page-id tag.